# Multiply glm::vec3 with boost multiprecision float

Tags: c++, boost, precision, glm-math

Boost offers a multiprecision library for floating-point values which is awesome, but glm does not allow for it to be multiplied with a vector or matrix or pretty much anything as it does not know what it is.

So the code below does **not** compile:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 mp_float;

    float a = 0.1f;
    mp_float b = 0.1f;

    glm::vec3 foo(1.f,1.f,1.f);

    glm::vec3 v1 = a * foo; // OK
    glm::vec3 v2 = b * foo; // COMPILER ERROR
}
```

Is there a way to make this work without having to go and write class wrappers and operator overloading member functions? ( I would really really like to avoid this )

Or if anyone knows  another method of multiplying with glm and high precision numbers, I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like multiprecision is not accepted by other libs..

Templates will save a lot of code, but at the end, one would have to specialize for the different operations! Also, it is possible to end up in the same problem when multiplying mp_float with T, and if T is float, then back to stage 0!

The best thing so far is to avoid using boost multiprecision with the glm library and control the precision with numeric_limits and rounding up numbers to 6 decimal places.

That's what I've ended up using and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can overload operators without wrapper classes:

```
glm::vec3 operator *(mp_float f, glm::vec3 v) {
    // ...
}
```

Note, though, that `glm::vec3` only holds normal `float`s, so you'll lose some precision doing this no matter how you do it.

Comment: Good suggestion! 

Yes, I'm aware you can do that but I'm trying to avoid operator overloading as a hole since I'll have to overload for almost all operators and for vec3's, vec4's, mat3's, mat4's..etc! Not something I want to spend my time doing..! :P

Unfortunately, glm::detail::tvec3<T> does not work either when you multiply with another number either int or float or mp_float. So the line: glm::detail::tvec3<mp_float> v3 = a * foo; will not compile even if "foo" and "a" are of type mp_float.

Comment: UPDATE: You can't even define a type of glm::detail::tvec3<mp_float> golf;

Comment: Ah, so you can't. Looks like you're limited to types with trivial copy constructors. I've edited that part out of my answer.

The other thing I can think of is defining the overloads as templates, so that you don't have to redefine them for each vector/matrix type: `template <typename T> T operator *(T v, mp_float f) { return v * f.convert_to<float>(); }`

Comment: seems like multiprecision is not accepted by other libs.. I tried with templates but you will still end up specializing for the operators! There is no way to avoid this. Templates will save a lot of code, but at the end you will have to specialize for the different operations!

Also, you will end up in the same problem... Multiplying mp_float with T, and if T is float, then back to stage 1! I think the best thing is to avoid using boost multiprecision with glm and use numeric_limits and rounding up numbers. That's what I've used and it works like a charm.. shame though!